# Solve 3 degree equation with given condition

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-curves

Given a 3. degree function:

$f(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$

Furthermore, I am given

- the graph of function $f(x)$ passes through x-axis at origin.
- the tangent at point P(-3, 0) is parallel with line $y = 6x$

How can I solve for a, b, c and d ?

So far I have,

Since graph passes through origin, 
$f(0) = 0$ 
so, 
$d = 0$   ----------- (1)

Graph also passes through P(-3, 0) so I get,

$0 = -27a + 9b -3c + d$  ----------- (2)

Now to get tangent of line at P(-3, 0) taking first derivative w.r.t $x$ I get,

$f'(x) = 3ax^2 + 2bx +c$

Since tangent is parallel to $y = 6x$, we get slope $m = 6$

$6 = 27a - 6b + c$  ----------- (3)

How can I get fourth equation to solve for all the values.

> EDIT 2: Condition 1 (first bullet point), in German:
>
> ```
>  - Die Graph von f berührt die x-Achse im Ursprung
> ```

*EDIT: Could the catch be in the first condition where it explicitly mentions that curve passes the 'x-axis' at origin. Giving another condition for curvature/maxima of the curve. Just my assumption here.*

Comment: Tangent also passes through (-3,0).

Comment: You are doing right. You can't find $a,b,c$, but you can put $b$ and $c$ as  a function of $a$ and find the general result.

Comment: I don't think you have enough information. Are you sure you have stated the problem correctly? As is, the answer is a one parameter family of cubics.

Comment: @StubbornAtom The OP has already used that fact since the curve goes through $(-3,0)$ at that point of tangency.

Comment: @EthanBolker well the original question was in German so I might have lost some information there. However, My guess so far is that the information given in first condition that graph passes the 'x-axis' at origin gives two different condition. 1. it passes through origin. 2. it gives concavitiy of the graph. could it be? If so I can get another equation and solve it.

Comment: At best "passes"  would provide an inequality. Can you quote the original German? There are often German speakers on this site.

Comment: @EthanBolker added it as edit 2. Hope someone reads it. Thanks

Comment: Google translates "berührt" as "touches" so maybe they just mean the x-axis is tangent at the origin?

Comment: @user96233 exactly! Thanks that solves it. Found another solution: https://www.mathelounge.de/106477/eine-parabel-3-ordnung-beruhrt-im-ursprung-die-x-achse which explains the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

So credit goes to this answer from [mathlounge.de](https://www.mathelounge.de/106477/eine-parabel-3-ordnung-beruhrt-im-ursprung-die-x-achse) and all the comments with discussion.

Apparently for the fourth equation, 
Since f passes/touches x-axis at origin, f has a horizontal tangent line with slope = 0. This gives, 
$f'(0) = 0$

which means

$c = 0$

and the rest can be solved now. Thanks guys for all the comments.